# How to live stream output from ruby script using child_process.spawn

Tags: ruby, node.js, child-process

From what I understand, this should work, but no luck for me so far. Posting this question hoping I'm doing something really silly. I have:

**hello.rb**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

3.times do
  puts 'hello'
  sleep 1
end
```

**tail.js**

```
var cp = require('child_process');
var tail = cp.spawn('./hello.rb');

tail.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);

/* Also tried this: */
tail.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log(data.toString())
});
```

`hello.rb` is executable.

When I run `node tail.js`, 3 hellos are printed to stdout, but *after*, the loop completes. You can verify this by changing `3.times` to just `loop` for an infinite loop and seeing nothing in `stdout`. The infinite loop case is actually what I'm attempting to figure out how to do.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try either adding `$stdout.flush` after your `puts` or by setting `$stdout.sync = true` at the beginning of your ruby script.

Comment: That worked, than you! Could you add a little bit about what that does?

Comment: I also edited the question title/tags to reflect that this had more to do with ruby than `child_process` or node.

Comment: `$stdout.flush` flushes the current stdout buffer since writing to stdout is asynchronous by default.

`$stdout.sync = true` switches to synchronous stdout output, which disables the stdout buffer and ensures that each write is flushed before continuing execution.